# Comparing date and time in python

Tags: python, string, class, date, time

I need to compare the time (and date if that helps) that a message was sent to see if it was in the past 24 hours.

Does anyone know how to take said time and see if it was in the past 24 hours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need to learn about the Python `datetime` module. Here is a method that solves your problem using `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

def is_older_than_a_day(test_time):
    one_day_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)

    if test_time > one_day_ago:
        print "The test time is less than one day old!"
    else:
        print "The test time is older than one day."
```

(Notice, `test_time` is the timestamp of your message as a `datetime` object.) Basically, I used three helpful features from the `datetime` module:

- `datetime.now()` will get the current time
- `timedelta` allows you to adjust/change a datetime by a given number of `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, etc.
- Two `datetime` objects can be compared with the operators: `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, `==`, `!=`

Comment: Should of thanked you earlier, but thank you